# Laravel nova tool not working with Class not found error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-nova

I'm creating a tool with laravel nova.

I ran this command first,

```
php artisan nova:tool mytools/cachier
```

And then in my mai app directory App\Providers\NovaServiceProvider I added,

```
use Mytools\Cachier\Cachier;

public function tools()
    {
        return [
            new Cachier(),
        ];

    }
```

This is my tool composer json

```
{
    "name": "mytools/cachier",
    "description": "A Laravel Nova tool.",
    "keywords": [
        "laravel",
        "nova"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.1.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Mytools\\Cachier\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "providers": [
                "Mytools\\Cachier\\ToolServiceProvider"
            ]
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

But now when I'm trying to access app I'm getting this error.

> Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError
>   (E_ERROR) Class 'Mytools\Cachier\Cachier' not found

It would be great if someone can help :'(

Answer (score 12):

For anyone googling this--or OP if you haven't figured it out yet--I had this issue because I didn't run the composer or npm commands while generating the tool. Try `composer update mytools/cachier` from the project root.

Comment: Thanks for posting this answer, super helpful over a year later!

Comment: Glad my pain and suffering could be of benefit!

Answer (score -2):

Check the `namespace` that you imported:

```
use Mytools\Cachier\Cachier; // <----

public function tools()
    {
        return [
            new Cachier(),
        ];

    }
```

I think it should be:

```
use Mytools\Cachier; // <----

// ...
```

PS: Also, check the `namespace` defined inside your class to match this one.

Comment: did you run `composer dump-autoload`?